# Is there a way to see which of 2 JComboBox's has been modified in the ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I have 2 JComboBox's in my app and when I change the value of 1 combobox it has to do something else than when I change the other combobox.
When I change the first, the values of the the second should be modified but when I change the second it should do nothing.
So is there a way to see which combobox has been changed?

Thanks!

Comment: [`EventObject.getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure, you should check `event.getSource()` to find the one you're interested in:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Object src = event.getSource();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using the getSource() wrong so that's why I couldn't figure it out..

Comment: @MaartenMeeusen, ` I was using the getSource() wrong so that's why I couldn't figure it out` - so post your code showing what you have tried when you post a question. You will get a better answer sooner if people think you have actually tried something.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the next time. I havn't posted many questions yet so.. :) Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to differentiate them from the ActionEvent's `getSource()` Object.

Alternatively, you can set a different "Action Command" using the [setActionCommand()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29) method and [getActionCommand()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand%28%29)

Comment: getSource() did the trick. Also thanks for the alternative. I did not knew about that one.

Answer (score 3):

You can also directly add an anonymous actionListener to the combobox you need to listen for:

```
comboOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        // make changes to comboTwo
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice, this can be very handy!